# Combine lists of dictionaries with specific value matches

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a_list and b_list in python, I want to merge them so that the result is c_list.

In the example below, only want to merge elements that have a matching 'A' for the 'code' key.

```py
a_list = [{'code': 'A', 'foo_sum': 1}, {'code': 'B', 'foo_sum': 2}]
b_list = [{'code': 'A', 'bar_sum': 3}]

c_list = [{'code': 'A', 'foo_sum': 1, 'bar_sum': 3}, {'code': 'B', 'foo_sum': 2}]
```

I wanted to use numpy, but could not use it because it did not necessarily match the element length and the order.

And, I tried to determine this in the iterative process, but could not achieve to make it c because local variables are not available in the comprehension notation.

```py
for a in b_list:
    if any(b["code"] == a["code"] for i, b in enumerate(b_list):
        # want to use i variable, but not dified.
        a["bar_sum"] = b_list[i]["code"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
a_list = [{"code": "A", "foo_sum": 1}, {"code": "B", "foo_sum": 2}]
b_list = [{"code": "A", "bar_sum": 3}]


out = {}
for d in a_list + b_list:
    out[d["code"]] = {**out.get(d["code"], {}), **d}

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```py
[{"code": "A", "foo_sum": 1, "bar_sum": 3}, {"code": "B", "foo_sum": 2}]
```

Comment: Could you please provide some explanations on `**` application here?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Its dictionary *unpacking*: `{**{"a": 1, "b": 2}, **{"c": 3}}` becomes `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`. In newer Pythons you can use `{"a": 1, "b": 2} | {"c": 3}`

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej, it seems like an interesting technique.

Comment: Thank you for nice solution! I will take this as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1. merge the two lists
2. sort the merged list by `code` key then groupby `code`
3. merge the list of dictionary in group to one dictionary

```py
from itertools import groupby
from collections import ChainMap

c_list = a_list + b_list
c_list = sorted(c_list, key=lambda d: d.get('code'))
res = [dict(ChainMap(*group)) for key, group in groupby(c_list, lambda d: d.get('code'))]
```

```
print(res)

[{'code': 'A', 'bar_sum': 3, 'foo_sum': 1}, {'code': 'B', 'foo_sum': 2}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I was able to reproduce this one with no problems.